# Redirect a specific IP address to a special page of my homepage with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

How can I use .htaccess to forward a visitor of a specific IP address to a webpage on my server?

This example causes an infinite loop:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^123\.\123\.123\.123$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /specialpage.php [R,L]
```

I found this on the web but it just does not work:

```
SetEnvIf REMOTE_ADDR 123.123.123.123 REDIR="redir"
RewriteCond %{REDIR} redir
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /specialpage.php
```

Note: My website consists of .htm, html and .php pages.

Your help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a condition to *not* rewrite when you're already at specialpage:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^123\.\123\.123\.123$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/specialpage.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /specialpage.php [R,L]
```

Comment: Almost! Unfortunately, the CSS is not loaded anymore now. Any help?

Comment: @jim-knopf I edited this answer to overcome the CSS/JS issue, but it wasn't accepted for some reason. In case others stumble across this thread, the answer should also include the following line (just above the RewriteRule: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif|css|js) [NC]`

Answer (score 1):

Just figured out the solution:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^123\.\123\.123\.123$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/specialpage.php
RewriteRule .*\.(htm|html|php)$ /specialpage.php [R,L]
```

Thank you for your help!