# Load different page based on IP-range

Tags: javascript, apache, .htaccess, clientip

I would like to load different content within Index page based on Country IP range. Is it possible ?

Comment: Yes you can do that. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439308/redirect-a-specific-ip-address-to-a-special-page-of-my-homepage-with-htaccess

Comment: I don't want to redirect to another page but to load different content. So for example when IP 122.25.67.156 access my site, the url will be mysite.com but with different content.

Comment: @Blazer then what's `mod_rewrite` for?

Comment: If you dont want to use apache `mod_rewrite` , i suggest you to do this on server side. Get IP address of client and send it to ajax as `json`. Than you can change any content of any page.

Comment: I'm really new into this. Using mod_rewrite means redirect ? I need the easiest way to change content of home index page if certain IP's access my site.

Comment: If you use a `RewriteRule` without the `R` flags, it will create an internal redirect that is not visible to the user.