# Load different Home Page for IP ranges with override available

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect, drupal

I received a request for one of our websites to load a different webpage for a series of IP ranges (about 3) that will show completely different information, theme, etc.

I did look at this page [Redirect a specific IP address to a special page of my homepage with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439308/redirect-a-specific-ip-address-to-a-special-page-of-my-homepage-with-htaccess) but it is not specific enough.

I am assuming somethings below, but for good reason, since I can see them being requested.

This is what I am looking to do, most likely using the .htaccess file. And this is in a Drupal environment, but the page I want them to go to will be a static HTML page I make.

***Basically I am trying to make a splash page show for particular IP ranges...***

- Only takes place when the user visits Home Page or site root.
- If visitor has IP ranges of XX.XXX.XXX.* , XX.XXX.XXX.* , or XX.XXX.XXX.* redirect internal/index.html
- If user then wants to proceed to the main website and see all it's goodness, and they click the "Continue to site" button, they are redirected back to the normal website.

As I type this, I can already see this being a couple of steps, please correct me where I am wrong.

- In order to handle the last request, a session cookie will need to be in place that remembers that the user chose to go back to the normal site (kind of the same way some mobile sites have the "view full site" option).
- Since Drupal is db fed, the .htaccess file is the fastest and easiest way (i think) to first handle the redirect. I could however modify the html.tpl.php file to handle the request as well, if it needs to be done via php.

I know I kind of answered my own question, kind of, but I am still unfamiliar how to perform the above in PHP.

**Update**

I did find this, that may help with the initial redirect. Though allowing someone to then override this so they can then go to the normal site is beyond me.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=123.45.67.
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=123.45.68.
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=123.45.69.
RewriteRule index.php$ internal/newhomepage.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: you don't need a session cookie. just **A** cookie. mod_rewrite can test for the IP, test for the cookie, and redirect (or not) as appropriate.